# Electron - Transparent Window with non-transparent font

Tags: electron

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    transparent: true,
    frame: false,
    fullscreen: true,
    backgroundColor: "#000"
    opacity: 0.5,
})
mainWindow.setIgnoreMouseEvents(true)
```

When setting the `backgroundColor` to `#000` I somewhat expected that only the background of the window matching #000 would be transparent but it turns out that the other elements such as the fonts become transparent as well.